# Dialog on AppCompatActivity has no title. Why?

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme, android-dialog, appcompatactivity

I'm compiling with API 27 and displaying a Dialog on a AppCompatActivity with this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And the theme for the full application is this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I'm displaying the dialog using this code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.setTitle("Valorar " + APP_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(sv);        
dialog.show();
```

The problem is that the dialog is shown without title and I don't understand why.

Am I doing something wrong with the Activity theme or the Dialog creation logic?

Comment: did u try it with using activity or fragment activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `AlertDialog` instead of just a plain `Dialog`. If you use the support library version of `AlertDialog`, you'll also get material design (instead of Holo) on older API levels.

This will also work around your activity's theme clobbering the dialog's title.

For you, the change is simple:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
        .setTitle("Valorar " + APP_TITLE)
        .setView(sv)
        .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and you're correct. Alert dialogs don't show a title bar in a NoActionBar activity, I had to specifically define an alertDialogTheme within my NoActionBar theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/<your dialog theme></item>
</style>
```

you could use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` (or similar) directly above or define your own with it as the parent

Comment: how can I specify the theme for my dialog? and how can I specify in that sample that I want it with title? Please can you improve your sample? Thanks

Comment: This would be part of your "AppTheme.NoActionBar" style, I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

This disables the title, set it to `false` ..

```
 <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

*From your Activity theme*

**Programatically you can try** :-

```
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
   Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
```